# CSS Issue with my HTML5 Canvas PitchDeck

Tags: css, html

An issue is arising (something in my CSS I presume) with my PitchDeck Web App: Kimerick: http://kimerick.com/.

Specifically, when using Chrome or Safari notice the arrows in the lower right corner. Only in Chrome and Safari, the left arrow is not sized appropriately (with relation to the other arrows). Yet, in Opera and Firefox all of the arrows are sized the same.

The CSS can be found here: http://kimerick.com/css/main.css. The class in question is ".controls".

Any ideas or thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The arrows all seem properly sized to me in Chrome. Try clearing your cache in both browsers, and use CTRL-F5 to completely refresh the page.

Comment: That is a good sign then - Thanks. I have cleared cache often for development testing but I will check on another machine.